# Doc about app.yaml for Java GAE standard environment

Tags: java, google-app-engine, app.yaml

All is in the title, i googled it yet and nothing...
Someone can help me giving some explaination about using this file?

PS: already seen the doc for python and php env but it's not about java env (like servlet, filters...)

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly found the doc, but its a little old...

I used it anyway

Here the doc: [Doc app.yaml GAE Java Standard Env](http://free-online-ebooks.appspot.com/google/google-appengine-docs-20110211/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/)

Answer (score 0):

The Java standard environment is the only one which does not use the `app.yaml` config file.

The (closest) equivalent is the [`appengine-web.xml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appref), whose's reference page you're getting from any language's [`app.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref) reference page if you click on the `Java` language tab.

See also Java's [Configuration Files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configuration-files).

Comment: Thanks but i use the app.yaml already on my dev project on eclipse and it do generate web.xml and appengine-web.xml automaticly so i just need to know how it work?

Comment: Ah, then follow one of the other languages reference guide - the semantics and the syntax are (pretty much) identical.

Comment: Yes but for all the Java's things like servlet and filter words how can I do?

Comment: That's why I'd recommend switching to `appengine-web.xml` - there's so much that can be auto-translated from `app.yaml`, some Java stuff doesn't have `app.yaml` equivalents. Use the currently generated `appengine-web.xml` as initial version if you don't want to start from scratch.